# If else statement, equal or lesser than value

Tags: java, swing

I have the following codes for a button to get my group:

```
char group = 0;

if (Integer.parseInt(lblTbt.getText()) <= 30) {
    group = 'A';
} else if (Integer.parseInt(lblTbt.getText()) <=60) {
    group = 'B';

lblGroup.setText(String.valueOf(group));
```

but in another button I'm want to get a decimal value.

I try with the same code but with error.

```
double rf = 0;

if (Integer.parseInt(lblSurface.getText()) <= 29) {
   rf = '1.1';
} else if (Integer.parseInt(lblSurface.getText()) <=59) {
    rf = '1.3';

lblRF.setText(String.valueOf(RF));
```

I wanted to get the rf (decimal value) and setText into a label.

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: check your datatypes! and note, that variable names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change: `rf = '1.1';` into: `rf = 1.1;`

Also, probably you will need: `lblRF.setText(String.valueOf(rf));` instead of using `RF`

Comment: And he is using `RF` in `String.valueOf`. lol you missed that;)

Answer (score 0):

Oh goodness.  Okay, first, you've declared rf as a double but you're assigning '1.1' to it.  try making rf a string.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you declared a double variable and assign to it a character. That bis the issue. Remove those quotes and problem solved. Also, change `String.valueOf(RF)` to `String.valueOf(rf)`

```
double rf = 0;

if (Integer.parseInt(lblSurface.getText()) <= 29) {
   rf = 1.1;
} else if (Integer.parseInt(lblSurface.getText()) <=59) {
    rf = 1.3;

 lblRF.setText(String.valueOf(rf));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble, I just realised I used the code at the wrong button.

The code is working fine now.:

```
    double rf = 0;

    if (Integer.parseInt(lblSurface.getText()) <= 29) {
       rf = 1.4;
    } else if (Integer.parseInt(lblSurface.getText()) <=59) {
        rf = 1.2;


}
    lblRF.setText(String.valueOf(rf));
```